# sort json nested array based on index not working as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a json array and I want to sort the array based on its index number

```
[  
   {  
      "name":"abc",
      "index":2,
      "values":[  
         {  
            "work":"three3",
            "index":3
         },
         {  
            "work":"one1",
            "index":1
         },
         {  
            "work":"two2",
            "index":2
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "name":"pqr",
      "index":1,
      "values":[  
         {  
            "work":"three",
            "index":3
         },
         {  
            "work":"two",
            "index":2
         },
         {  
            "work":"one",
            "index":1
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

What I expect from this array is:

```
[  
   {  
      "filename":"pqr",
      "children":[  
         {  
            "work":"one",
            "index":1
         },
         {  
            "work":"two",
            "index":2
         },
         {  
            "work":"three",
            "index":3
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "filename":"abc",
      "children":[  
         {  
            "work":"one1",
            "index":1
         },
         {  
            "work":"two2",
            "index":2
         },
         {  
            "work":"three3",
            "index":3
         }
      ]
   }
   ]
```

Tried something like below.

```
const filterBy = (arr, childname, filterText) =>
{
    return arr.map(({filename, children}) =>
    {
        return {filename, children: children.map(({filename, children}) =>
        {
           if (filename === childname)
               return {filename, children: children.filter(
                   x => x.filename.match(filterText)
               )};
           else
               return {filename, children};
        })};
    });
}
```

It is a json array and what we can not be sure it will be in order so I want an array or object should be in sorted order

But how can I include that index in inner level and outer level and sort using it accordingly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first sort the array based on `index`. This will return a sorted array now use `map`. Inside the callback function get the `values` array and again sort it.Inside the array map function return the object with required key and value

```js
let data = [{
    "name": "abc",
    "index": 2,
    "values": [{
        "work": "three3",
        "index": 3
      },
      {
        "work": "one1",
        "index": 1
      },
      {
        "work": "two2",
        "index": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "pqr",
    "index": 1,
    "values": [{
        "work": "three",
        "index": 3
      },
      {
        "work": "two",
        "index": 2
      },
      {
        "work": "one",
        "index": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]


let newdt = data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.index - b.index
}).map(function(item) {
  let val = item.values.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.index - b.index;
  })

  return {
    name: item.name,
    children: val
  }
})
console.log(newdt)
```

Answer (score 1):

First sort the outer array, use same function to sort inner array

```js
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a.index < b.index)
    return -1;
  if (a.index > b.index)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

var objs = [{
    "name": "abc",
    "index": 2,
    "values": [{
        "work": "three3",
        "index": 3
      },
      {
        "work": "one1",
        "index": 1
      },
      {
        "work": "two2",
        "index": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "pqr",
    "index": 1,
    "values": [{
        "work": "three",
        "index": 3
      },
      {
        "work": "two",
        "index": 2
      },
      {
        "work": "one",
        "index": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]


var result = objs.sort(compare).map(function(item) {
  var children = item.values.sort(compare);
  return {
    filename: item.name,
    children: children
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: check expected & your output

Comment: You can make the `compare` function more generic by passing the key by which it will be sorted. Assume it is not `index` key for bot the case then this compare function will fail